# To characterise diameter of capillaries in organs

Tags: physiology, blood-circulation

I know that there exist Continuous capillaries (skeletal muscle, adipose tissue, connective tissue, pulmonary circulation), Fenestrated capillaries (small intestine, renal glomerulus, exocrine glands), and Discontinuous capillaries (sinusoids; liver, spleen, bone marrow and hypophysis).

However, I am not sure how to characterise these.
The diameter of capillaries is different for each.
I have not managed to find any figure which present the relationship of diameter of these capillaries.
I have reviewed books Guyton, Pocock and Lange.

**What are the diameters of capillaries in different organs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is dependent on the specific patient at hand.
I think in the normal situation the diameter of the capillaries is about the same in each organ.
Better question would be: how does the diameter changes in relation to the venous and arterial ends of the capillaries?
Then, think about how big portion of the capillaries are in the venous end in the organ.

I cannot say that 50% of capillaries are on the venous end of the organ and 50% on the arterial side.
This is again an open research question.